# Is it possible to share a project without commiting?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'd like to use "Share Project..." in Eclipse without actually commiting to SVN. Unfortunately, I am not able to find an option for doing this.

Instead, I want the relevant files only be added to SVN.

My goal is, that SVN should track all the files I move into the project using the package explorer.

Comment: Sharing on SVN without committing sounds like a no-go. Perhaps you are thinking about having things shared somehow without having them committed on your central repo? Sounds like you are already inclined to learn about DVCS without realizing it yet.

Comment: @eftshift0 Unfortunately, I am not able to change my VCS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share Project needs to accomplish two things:

1. It sets up some internal linkage in Eclipse that connects your project with the SVN Team Provider so that SVN menu actions are exposed and so that activities you perform are routed to the SVN provider to "handle".
2. It has to establish your project as SVN "working copy" so that the SVN API that needs to be called on behalf of your actions can do what it needs to do.

So the key here is that if you already have a SVN working copy then Share Project will recognize this and be able to do option 1 without needing to do anything else.  But otherwise, it has to establish a working copy which requires it to do `svn checkout` from your repository.  If it has to create the working copy then it makes the assumption it needs to create the project in the repos and then check that out on top of your local project.  So the one commit it will do is a `svn mkdir` for a folder in the repos.

If you do not want to do that, then do something to establish a working copy locally before you get started, such as checking out some existing location in your repository.  As others have noted, you may want to be using branches and switch if you are refactoring something that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

When you commit data to the SVN repository, you publish this new data or make changes to existing data (i.e. you make your changes available to others). Therefore, you need to commit your changes if you want others to see it in your SVN repository and collaborate.

As far as I recall, "Share Project" command in Eclipse is designed to import your non-versioned project to the SVN repository (i.e. make a first-time import) -- it converts your local data into a working copy and commits it.

I do not understand what exactly you mean by "share but not commit" (you may want to elaborate). However, you can always select which files to add and commit or import into the repository, but I guess that you will need to use standalone SVN client outside of Eclipse.

Comment: My problem boils down to the following, frequent scenario:

I have multiple projects opened in eclipse that are already commited to SVN and "shared" via subclipse. Now I have to do some refactoring.
I create a new project and add the files to SVN via commandline. Now I move classes from other projects to my new project. Since Subclipse doesn't realize that the folder is already added to SVN, it doesn't register the move in SVN and my history is lost. This is the problem I want to fix somehow. I'd like to avoid commiting the empty project after creating it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understand what you meant but I **think** what you are describing is screaming for new branches to be created for your refactoring so that you don't lose history.